# Finding the size of a NewArrayExpression

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

When trying to parse an expression tree using the following:

```
private static XElement Parse(NewArrayExpression newArray)
{
    IEnumerable<XElement> items = newArray.Expressions
        .Select(item => new XElement(ExpressionTag.NewArrayItem, Parse((dynamic)item)));

    return new XElement(ExpressionTag.NewArrayNode, items);
}
```

I've found that passing in `new Int32[5]` produces identical information to `new Int32[] { 5 }` in that the `NewArrayExpression.Expressions` property just gets filled in with what I imagine are supposed to be the construction parameters. The problem is there's no way to tell when the parameter is a *length* or if it is an actual *item*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/system.linq.expressions.newarrayexpression.expressions.aspx):

`NewArrayExpression.Expressions` Property

> Gets the bounds of the array if the value of the NodeType property is
>   NewArrayBounds, or the values to initialize the elements of the new
>   array if the value of the NodeType property is NewArrayInit.

Essentially, branching on the `NodeType` property will help you disambiguate.

Comment: Sick dude, that's perfect. It's either `NewArrayBounds` or `NewArrayInit`. Thanks!